# Gatling - login and logout once and loop thru other scenarios multiple times

Tags: scala, gatling

Following is my scenario, I need to run the below test with 5 users for 10 minutes. Flow is login -> verification -> 360screen --> logout. I need all the 5 users to login and run verification and 360 screen for about 10 minutes and logout 1 by one. I dont want the test to run login and logout multiple times. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Use a [during](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/scenario/#loop-statements) loop. This is a very basic question, so you should take some time to read the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/) and have a look a the [Gatling Academy](https://gatling.io/academy/).

Comment: Not sure if 'During' will work. I have 2 scripts 1. login, verification, home and logout 2. login, verification, home, change address and logout. I have a master script where I call these 2 scripts using setUp function. Test scenario 20 min and 10 users. first 5 min all 10 users will ramp up(will run both the scripts except logout step). Next 10 minutes steady state, 10 users will be in the system(both the scripts except logout). Last 5 minutes users will start to ramp down and will execute logout in both the scripts.

Comment: class AllSimulation extends Simulation {
  
   setUp(
       new RecordedSimulation().scn.inject(atOnceUsers(2)).protocols(new RecordedSimulation().httpProtocol),
       new TCS().scn.inject(atOnceUsers(2)).protocols(new TCS().httpProtocol)
       )
} both RecordedSimulation and TCS are having the following functions, login, verification, home and logout. I want 10 users to ramp up in 5 minutes and steady state for 10 minutes and then ramp down. I want the users to execute logout only during ramp down in both the scripts.

Comment: Stephane Landelle, can you please help on this?

Comment: If you're looking for mentoring/consulting, feel free to reach out: https://gatling.io/consulting-and-training/.

Comment: I will check on that, but any insight on how to implement the above scenario?